# How to add more than one file extension to extensionless urls

Tags: php, asp.net, .htaccess, url

I already have extensionless urls working for html but the site in question used to have php and aspx files years ago that are showing up as 404s also. Can someone tell me where to add php and aspx to the following:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So the old url was: `http://example.com/about.php` and the new is `http://example.com/about`? To remove php and aspx extension as well you could change your regex to something like: `^(.+)\.(html|php|aspx)$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add those extensions to the RewriteCond and RewriteRule's pattern :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.(html|php|aspx)
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(html|php|aspx)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't work, Internal server error. I am assuming there is a space on each side of the pipe character. Yes?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when I copied the code above it added spaces around the pipe character. I took out the spaces and then it worked.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.(html|php|aspx)
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(html|php|aspx)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks.